# MS Word InsertBreak throws exception

Tags: c++, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm getting error "Type mismatch" when trying to InsertBreak via Range using parameters (for instance, wdPageBreak or wdLineBreak). But it's ok, to InsertBreak parameterless. Am I the only one getting such a behaviour, or is it another Word API bug?

```
//MS Word VBA Reference
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(2).Range 
With myRange 
 .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
 .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak 
End With
```

---

```
//c++ code
HRESULT hr = pWordDoc->GetParagraphs()->Item(1)->GetRange()->
        InsertBreak(&variant_t(Word::wdPageBreak));  //hr = 0x80020005 TypeMismatch
hr = pWordDoc->GetParagraphs()->Item(1)->GetRange()->
            InsertBreak(&vtMissing);                 // hr = S_OK
```

Comment: did you check the value of `&variant_t(Word::wdPageBreak)` runtime to know what are you passing into InsertBreak?

Comment: @Simo variant_t is just a wrapper wich automatically creates a VARIANT which is to be passed as a parameter. For enum correspondig enum INT is passed.In almost all other functions which require a variant, wrapping such enum works fine. Have you tried cidde from MS reference?

Comment: If it was working fine than why did it throw such error?

Comment: @Simo it was not working fine with this particular method. The only way to create a page break, is not to pass any parameters, though you mentioned that is wrong. I can live with that until the occasion when I need to create a line break, for example...

Comment: Is your problem with the VBA code or the C++ code.

Comment: @StevenLaycock the problem is with the C++ code, as per the comments in the code posted.

Comment: Well, to get you past the problem I can tell you how to insert the characters as part of a string... ANSI 12 is a page break, ANSI 11 is a line break, ANSI 13 is a new paragraph.

Comment: @StevenLaycock I've posted this question to know if this propblem occurs using VBA, since I don't use VBA and can't figure out myself.

Comment: @CindyMeister It would be OK for an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no way to get the C++ version of this part of Word's object model to function correctly you can work around it by using the ANSI character codes to insert certain kinds of breaks. (They can also be used to search/identify the breaks in a document's text.)

```
Page break:      ANSI 12 (= press Ctrl+Enter)
Line break:      ANSI 11 (= press Shift+Enter)
Paragraph break: ANSI 13 (= press Enter)
```

Note that ANSI 12 is also the character code for the various types of *section break*; a page break is the default, so you're OK inserting the ANSI code if a page break is what's wanted.

In order to insert a Section Break it's possible to use the `Sections.Add` method. This accepts parameters indicating where the section break should be in the document and of what type. Method signature:

```
expression.Add(Range, Start)
```

Where `expression`is a variable that represents a Sections collection. (`wordDoc.Sections.Add` for example)

Valid values for `Start` come from the `WdSectionStart` enumeration:

```
wdSectionContinuous 0 Continuous section break. 
wdSectionEvenPage   3 Even pages section break. 
wdSectionNewColumn  1 New column section break. 
wdSectionNewPage    2 New page section break. 
wdSectionOddPage    4 Odd pages section break.
```